# SQL - Return latest comment for every row

Tags: mysql

So i have two tables, one has all the data and other has a list of comments and I need to load the latest comment for each row in the data table. Here's how it looks like

Table: `queries`

```
id    | name       |
--------------------
1     | John Doe   |
2     | Jane Doe   |
3     | Alex Smith |
```

Table: `messages`

```
id    | queriesId  | comment     | dateAdded           |
--------------------------------------------------------
1     | 1          | Comment 1   | 2016-06-12 15:00:08 |
2     | 1          | Commetn 2   | 2016-06-12 15:01:08 |
3     | 2          | Comment 3   | 2016-06-12 15:05:35 |
4     | 2          | Comment 4   | 2016-06-12 15:06:35 |
```

I want the results to look like this

```
id    | name       | comment     | dateAdded           |
--------------------------------------------------------
1     | John Doe   | Commetn 2   | 2016-06-12 15:01:08 |
2     | Jane Doe   | Comment 4   | 2016-06-12 15:06:35 |
3     | Alex Smith | Null        | Null                |
```

I tried this code

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.comment,
  b.LastComment
FROM
  queries a
LEFT JOIN
  (
  SELECT
    `comment`,
    MAX(dateAdded) LastComment,
      queriesid
  FROM
    messages
  GROUP BY
    queriesid
) b ON a.id = b.queriesid
GROUP BY
  a.id
```

but the result I get is this

```
id    | name       | comment     | dateAdded           |
--------------------------------------------------------
1     | John Doe   | Commetn 1   | 2016-06-12 15:01:08 |
2     | Jane Doe   | Comment 3   | 2016-06-12 15:06:35 |
3     | Alex Smith | Null        | Null                |
```

So the only problem is comment is the first entry and not the one corresponding with the datetime column value. I've tried many alterations but it doesn't seems to be working. I'm sure it's a tiny tweak away from working but I can't seem to find it.

Any ideas?

Comment: which dbms are you using? mysql or sql server?

Comment: Back ticks on `\`comment\`` looks like MySQL.

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't have selected both tags, it's mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the max date and queryId in you subquery, as you did. Then join again to messages ON the date and id to get the comment.

edit: Like this

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.LastComment,
  comment.comment
FROM
  queries a
LEFT JOIN
  (
  SELECT
    MAX(messages.dateAdded) LastComment,
    messages.queriesid
  FROM
    messages
GROUP BY
    queriesid
) b ON a.id = b.queriesid
LEFT JOIN messages AS comment 
    ON comment.dateAdded = b.LastComment 
    AND comment.queriesid = b.queriesid
GROUP BY
  a.id
```

Comment: Could you show a example? I'm new to mysql how do I join the table on itself? And I saw the marked duplicate answer as well but it's quite different as it is for one table only

Comment: edited my answer :)

Comment: I see what you did there. Brilliant. Thanks a bunch

Comment: I think you could select MAX(id) from messages instead of the date. The id being the primary key the database could use the index for the second join. You should give it a try.

Comment: Yes that works too. I tried `....ON comment.id = b.LastComment
GROUP BY.....`. Which one should I pick? I don't think there'd be any performance benefit in either case.

Comment: Use the id, if there someday are A LOT of entries in the table the index will be needed.